# Issue with installing ethnicolr package

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

When I try to install ethnicolr, received an error

> "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.3(from ethniclor)"

Current version of tensorflow is 1.14, uninstalled it, and tried to install the version of 1.12.3 but get error complaining that could not find a version.

is there anyway to install the package?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install a previous version of ethnicolr

```
pip install ethnicolr==0.2.0
```

https://github.com/appeler/ethnicolr/issues/16